# Banach spaces in which every DP-set is a limited set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A\subseteq X$ be a bounded subset.
$A$ is a *Dunford-Pettis set* if every weakly null sequence $(f_n)$ in $X^*$ converges to $0$ uniformly on $A$, that is $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in A} |f_n(x)| = 0$$
$A$ is a *limited set* if every weak$^*$-null sequence in $X^*$ converges to $0$ uniformly on $A$.

We can show that the following are equivalent.

1. Every DP-set in $X$ is a limited set.
2. For every Banach space $Y$ and bounded $T:Y\to X$, if $T^*$ is completely continuous, then $T^*$ is sequentially weak$^*$-norm continuous.
3. Same as (2.) with $Y=\ell^1$.

Let's call the property above (DP=limited) property. Examples include Banach spaces with Schur property, Banach spaces with [(DPrc) property](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01190118) of [Emmanuele](https://www.dmi.unict.it/emmanuele/pubblicazioni/DPrcP.pdf), and Grothendieck spaces. To be a little more precise,

- $X$ has Schur property iff $X$ has Dunford-Pettis property (DPP), Gelfand-Phillips property (GPP), and (DP=limited) property.
- $X$ has (DPrc) property iff $X$ has GPP and (DP=limited) property.

> **Question:** *"$X$ is a Grothendieck space if $X$ has (DP=limited) property and .... "* Do you know of a condition that can replace the dots?

Has this property been considered before in the literature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the Gelfand-Phillips property?

Comment: A Banach space $X$ have the Gelfand-Phillips property if every limited subset of $X$ is relatively compact.